# High Performance Object Cache for Aiding Reflection

Tags: java, caching

I was wondering if anyone could give any advice. I have wrote a Json deserializer/serializer for several POJOs. In-order to make them as generic as possible, they rely on reflection to object the POJO getter/setter methods and so on. Since this is the biggest impact on performance, I attempted to create a sort of 'ClassUtils' cache, that would store the Method objects after being retrieved (I am using the Introspector to get the list of property descriptors, then getting the get/set methods from there)

However, I attempted to first use Guava LoadingCache - while it has some very nice and helpful features, it was terribly slow compared to the custom cache I created - 3.5 seconds to serialize 1,000 objects with the Guava cache, and only <1 second with my own... however, my own cache lacks alot of the useful features of Guava (like clearing old entries and so on)

Is there any advice on improving either the Guava performance, or for improving a custom cache? I can't post any code really as it is for work, however my own custom cache is basically a wrapper around a HashMap that stores the PropertyDescriptors, using a String as a Key (I need to store the key as the full class name plus property name, e.g. "com.company.package.classes.myclass.property")

Comment: Use Jackson, optionally with [afterburner](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-afterburner) to replace reflection with byte code generation. Can't debug Guava without code, unfortunately. [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/) is still faster than the Guava port, but many features were only added to Guava.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use JSon. If you use a binary format you might get 10 - 100x the performance for serialization/deserialization depending on how complex your data structures are.  If you want performance, you will have you avoid making everything completely generic.

You can use a LinkedHashMap as a LRU cache with a few lines of code.

Storing each property as a separate key is about one order of magnitude slower than using proper objects. (Again this is less generic but much more efficient)

Comment: I have to use Json :( I have been experimenting with storing the properties as objects, i.e. storing the get/set/constructor method in an Object, with the property name as the key which seems to have improved speed a fair bit

Comment: Also, as each object storing the Methods is immutable, caching the hashcode has also improved performance

Comment: Instead of guess what the problem might be, when you run the code in a profiler, what do you see as the performance bottlenecks?  I suggest you turn on the memory and CPU profiling at the same time.